# Jquery ToolTip - working but needs tweaking

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, positioning

I'm using the code here : 
http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

This seems to work fine apart from an issue with a table.

My table is very wide, has over 80 columns and requires me to scroll to see it all. That's fine because of the layout it actually works well scrolling.

Each header has a tooltip assigned to it that gives details on the column below. Again this works well with one exception.

The tooltips starts to wrap as I get near to the right hand edge of the page, any header / tooltip that is of screen and requires scrolling to is also wrapped.

Is there anyway to get a fixed width on the tooltip regardless of where it appears on the page in relation to the right edge ?

This is the jquery :

```
/*
 * Tooltip script 
 * powered by jQuery (http://www.jquery.com)
 * 
 * written by Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
 * 
 * for more info visit http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery
 *
 */



this.tooltip = function(){  
    /* CONFIG */        
        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 20;       
        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result     
    /* END CONFIG */        
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    tooltip();
});
```

it is called using :

```
<a href="http://cssglobe.com" class="tooltip" title="Web Standards Magazine">Roll over for tooltip</a>
```

And styled using :

```
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background:#f7f5d1;
    padding:2px 5px;
    color:#333;
    display:none;
    }
```

Adding width:150 !important; works, but then when I get the right of the page the tooltip disappears off the page.

Any way to make it display right to left when it gets to the right hand edge ?

Comment: can you please post your code, so that we can see the problem

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: why you dont you add a width !important to the id tooltip in the css?

Comment: Thanks that works. But highlights another issue.